# How do I set a default scroll position for a component without scrolling the entire page in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll

I have a parent page that has to be scrollable. I have a calendar view withing that page that is also scrollable. However, I don't want the calendar to render and the view to have 1am at the top by default. I would like it to be scrolled about half way down and the user can scroll up or down in the component it self. However, everything I tried to do to solve this also scrolls the parent page. I think what is happening is it is scrolling the parent page and when that can no longer scroll anymore, it scrolls the component to where I want. Are there any ways to do this without scrolling the parent component?

I tried refs but but every time I did that the parent component would scroll

This is the code that I tried

```
export default function WeeklyCalendar({classes, clinicals, blockedTime, fileClinicalList}) {
  const calendarRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    calendarRef.current.scrollTo(0, 500);
  }, []);


  return (
    <div>
        <div
          style={{
            position: 'sticky',
            zIndex: '10',
            backgroundColor: PlatformStyles.LogoNavyBlue,
            width: '100%',
            top: '0px',
            left: '-10%',
            right: '50px',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
          }}
          >
          {days.map((day , index) => {
            let width = columnWidth
            if (index === 0) {
              width = '5%'
            }
            return (
              <div
              style={{
                position: '',
                display: 'inline-block',
                zIndex: 11,
                color: 'white'
                width,
                textAlign: 'center'
              }}
              >
              {day}    
            </div>
            )
            
          })}
        </div>
    <div
      ref={calendarRef}
      style={{
        scrollMarginTop: '1000px',
        height: '700px',
        position: 'relative', 
        marginLeft: '40px'
      }}
      >
        {hours.map((hour) => {

          let id = hour
          if (hour === 6) {
            id = 'scrollId'
          }

          return (
            <div
            key={hour}
            id={id}
            style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              top: `${(hour - 0.5) * multiplier + .51}%`,
              bottom: `${100 - (hour + 1) * multiplier}%`,
              left: '-2%',
              right: '0%',
              fontSize: '11px',
              textAlign: 'left',
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              alignItems: 'center'
            }}
          >
            {convertTime(hour)}
          </div>
          )
          
        })}
        
        {/* Adds line in the middle of the hour */}
        {hours.map((hour) => 
          <div
            key={hour}
            style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              top: `${hour * multiplier}%`,
              bottom: `${100 - (hour + 1) * multiplier}%`,
              left: '.5%',
              right: '0%',
              marginLeft: '22px',
              borderBottom: '1px solid lightgray',
              textAlign: 'left',
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              alignItems: 'center'
            }}
          >
          </div>
        )}
        {events.map((event, index) => 
          event.day.map((day) => 
          <Event
            key={`event-${index}-${day}`}
            event={event}
            day={day}
            />
          )
        )}
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the code you have tried? By using a `ref` and doing `ref.current.scrollTop = ref.current.scrollHeight / 2 - (ref.current.offsetHeight / 2)`, you should be able to set the default scroll-position without affecting the parent page.

Comment: I edited the post with the code that I have. I have also tried the ref around the main div and that doesn't work either

Answer (score 3):

The following should produce a component that has an initial scroll-height of half it's scroll-length (minus half of it's height).

```
  const ChildComponent = () => {
     const ref = useRef(null);

     useEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current){
           const elHeight = ref.current.offsetHeight / 2;
           ref.current.scrollTop = ref.current.scrollHeight / 2 - elHeight;
        }
     }, [ref.current]);

     return <div ref={ref}>...</div>
  }
```

If you do not want it to be *half* the scroll-height, you can set it statically too:

```
  const ChildComponent = () => {
     const ref = useRef(null);

     useEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current){
           ref.current.scrollTop = 200; // px
        }
     }, [ref.current]);

     return <div ref={ref}>...</div>
  }
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-keldysh-03x0v5?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: This is what I have found all over the place and logically it should work but for whatever reason I just can't seem to get it to happen

Comment: `ref.current` is not accepted by typescript. 
> React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: 'ref.current'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Mutable values like 'ref.current' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component.